# Invoking a custom field in a PHP function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

What is the correct way to implement the second function below?  The first function works fine but the second function does not correctly invoke a custom field in WordPress whose key is `_ni_cost_goods`.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) in your code on line 11

```
<?php
function round_price( $price = null, $multiplier = 1, $nearest = 1, $minus = 0 ) {
    if ( !empty( $price ) ) {
        // strip any extra characters from price
        $price = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $price);
        // perform calculations
        return ( round ( ( $price * $multiplier ) / $nearest ) * $nearest ) - $minus; 
    }
}

function add_gst( _ni_cost_goods = null, $multiplier = 1.1) {
    if ( !empty( _ni_cost_goods ) ) {
        // strip any extra characters from price
        _ni_cost_goods = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", _ni_cost_goods);
        // perform calculations
        return _ni_cost_goods * $multiplier; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to put a dollar sign before _ni_cost_goods

Comment: In your second function, wrap the 1.1 inside of quotes tags. Also, you need to make _ni_cost_goods as variables, so `$_ni_cost_goods`

Comment: @Adam it's a float type so you don't need quotes.

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake. OP also needs to pass in $price to the second function somehow, that's also causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second function, you have a few issues, the variables being passed to the function and the return.

```
function add_gst( $_ni_cost_goods = null, $multiplier = 1.1) {

    if ( !empty( $_ni_cost_goods ) ) {

        // strip any extra characters from price
        $_ni_cost_goods = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $price);

        // perform calculations
        return $_ni_cost_goods * $multiplier; 
    }
}
```

You'll noticed I added the `$` sign to the _ni_cost_goods in several places. That being said, you're also accessing a variable `$price` which isn't in scope for the function.

Comment: I've corrected the instance of $price you alluded to, it was actually supposed to be an instance of `_ni_cost_goods`.  I'll try run it and confirm everything works in a bit.

Comment: Glad you got your problem solved :)